# Как во Fragment получить id элемента из его layoutxml? Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

[image]

(listview находится в fragment_chats.xml) привязку xml я вынес в отдельную функцию.

Comment: у Вас подключен `synthetic`, зачем Вам вообще `findViewById`? Просто пишите `listofmessage` - студия предложит его импортировать из разметки

Comment: Класс Fragment не имеет метода findViewById(). Этот метод доступен в Активити или View. В колбэке фрагмента onCreateView() вы получаете View с вашей разметкой, в нем и ищите свои виджеты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я тоже сейчас работаю с фрагментами и изучаю дроид с котлином, возможно мы сможем помогать друг другу в некоторых вопросах https://vk.com/idleoerdman

можно обращаться просто: listofmessage. и дальше методы объекта или переменные